# 'Int object is not iterable error' in my recursive code, not sure where I went wrong

Tags: python

I'm trying to find all permutations of a string, as you can see in the code below:

```
def permute(self, nums):
    if len(nums) == 0 or len(nums) == 1:
        return nums

    perms = []

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        prefix = nums.pop(i)

        for permutation_of_suffix in self.permute(nums):
            perms.append([prefix].extend(permutation_of_suffix))

        nums.insert(i, prefix)

    return perms
```

However, this line:

```
perms.append([prefix].extend(permutation_of_suffix))
```

is throwing the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I'm not really sure why this is happening. What is wrong with creating a new list by wrapping prefix in `[]` then running `.extend()` on another existing list returned from the lower level of recursion.

Any advice or feedback on my code would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `permutation_of_suffix` is a integer and `self.permute(nums)` is list i suppose, insteal of extend use `append`

Comment: i dont know about the error message, but i know that your line won't work even after you fix the initial error because methods like `extend` will return a None after doing an inplace operation. So, you cannot "reuse" it as if it was returning the modified item, because it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did't see whats your logic, but I found issue in specified line

You cannot extend a number to list, that means

```
k=[3]
k.extend(4) #will through an error 
k.extend([4]) # will work will extend k list  , output k=[3,4]
```

Solution:

```
def permute(nums):
if len(nums) == 0 or len(nums) == 1:
    return nums

perms = []

for i in range(len(nums)):
    prefix = nums.pop(i)

    for permutation_of_suffix in permute(nums):
        k=[prefix]
        if type(permutation_of_suffix) == list:
            k.extend(permutation_of_suffix)
        else:
            k.extend([permutation_of_suffix])
        perms.append(k)

    nums.insert(i, prefix)

return perms
```

print(permute([1,2,3]))

output: `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]`